# problem with R enconding

Tags: r, codificação-de-caracteres, texto

Me pediram para fazer análises de textos e estou tendo problema com a codificação, alguém sabe como posso converter esses strings com acento diretamente?

Exemplo de como esta aparecendo o arquivo:

```
vocÃªs dizerem que nÃ£o!!! AtÃ© quando
```

Outro exemplo:

```
â¤ï¸(...) ComilanÃ§as Ã© amigo secreto na casa clean!ðŸŽ
```

Já tentei utilizar essa função:

```
stringi::stri_enc_detect(dados$text)
```

e obtive essa saída:

```
    [[1]]$Encoding
    [1] "UTF-8"        "windows-1252" "windows-1250" "UTF-16BE"     "UTF-16LE"     "Shift_JIS"    "windows-1254"
    [8] "IBM420_ltr"  

    [[1]]$Language
    [1] ""   "pt" "cs" ""   ""   "ja" "tr" "ar"

    [[1]]$Confidence
    [1] 1.00 0.63 0.28 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.02 0.01
```

Se alguem puder ajudar serei grato!

Comment: Qual o resultado quando você usa `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: Opa, o resultado foi o seguinte:

Comment: [1] "LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o problema esteja já na importação. Como você está importando os arquivos? Quando o default não funciona corretamente eu costumo tentar definindo `encoding = "UTF8"`.

Tenta:
read.csv("nomedoarquivo.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")

Qualquer coisa tenta ler aqui:
http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/

Comment: Muito obrigado!